# How to modify the corner radius on rounded rectangle in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, borders

I always ended up just creating a new rounded rectangle if the existing one don't work. Is there a way to modify the corner radius without having to create a new shape?

I know I can modify the bezier handle manually one-by-one, but I can't figure out how to do this in a more accurate way for all 4 corners.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In the new Adobe Illustrator CC, you can use 2 easy methods to change the corner radius of a rounded corner rectangle that has already been drawn:

## 1. By moving the round handles

Simply hold and drag the round blue handles in each corner.

[image: How to change the corder radius of a rounded rectangle]

## 2. By going in the Shape Options (more precise)

You can change the border radius of all four corners with precision by using the Shape Options and simply enter a new measurement for your corners.

To change only one corner or give a different corner radius value to each of them, click the chain in the middle and fill the corner radius field for each corner.

[image: How to change numerically the corners of a rounded rectangle]

Comment: I have neither shape button nor blue handles. I'm using CS6

Comment: I believe this answer has been rendered obsolete by Adobe's policy of constantly changing interface. Someone needs to tell Adobe an inconsistent interface is a bad thing.

Comment: In Illustrator CC 2018 I found this under: Appearance (panel) > FX > Stylize > Round Corners.

Comment: @PrestonBadeer Thanks for that.  Seems you need to start with an non-rounded-corner rectangle for this to work though.

Comment: To round only a specific corner: 1. Deselect everything; 2. Use the "Direct Selection Tool (A)" to select *only* the specific corner; 3. Drag the "Live Corner" handles (i.e., the blue circle handles) as desired, or adjust more precisely via the "Corners" field on the control panel.

Comment: You can find the Shape options under "More Options" in the Transform section of the Properties panel.

Answer (score 49):

It seems like the best way is to use the Stylize/Round Corners effect on a regular rectangle. This way the corner radius is changeable and independent of the rectangle transform property.

With this method, the **Appearance** panel will have a ***Round Corners*** setting for any round rectangle paths. This will allow you to edit the corner radius for existing shapes.

[image: Appearance Panel with Round Corners]

Comment: But too bad that if you then use that path as a Clipping Mask the rounding effect will break. And if you do the Clipping Mask first, then try to add the Round Corners effect the image disappears. If trying to use this method with a Clipping Mask you can't win.

Answer (score 36):

While drawing rounded rectangle (while still holding your mouse button), press <kbd>UP</kbd> and <kbd>DOWN</kbd> arrows to change radius. This is a common way of changing attribute values of certain tools in AI.

Comment: While true, this doesn't answer the question of editing after the rectangle has been drawn.

Comment: Thanks, that's a simple and really helpful trick.

Answer (score 8):

Try using Convert to Shape effect: `Effect → Convert to Shape → Rounded Rectangle`.

Answer (score 7):

Seems you've already figured out that the Stylize Effect is a better method. If you want to go one step further check out VectorScribe from http://www.astutegraphics.com it's a fabulous plug in that will allow you to not only continually round any corner but also had many other very useful features.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone comes across this question in 2021 and is tearing their hair out, here is an updated solution.

#### Use the Transform panel

Illustrator allows you to edit corners precisely in the Transform panel only when the object is a "Rectangle Shape", which therefore has "Rectangle Properties", which include corner radius.

[image: Transform panel]

#### What if you don't see the Rectangle Properties?

Drawing a rectangle with the Rectangle tool creates a "Rectangle Shape" object.

Any other way of creating a rectangle (e.g. if you load a file from an SVG perhaps) will give you a **path that happens to be rectangular**. Illustrator won't recognise it as a "Rectangle Shape" object.

To convert a rectangular path into a Rectangle Shape:

1. Select the rectangles you want to convert.
2. Go to the menu Object > Shape > Convert to Shape
3. This will create a Rectangle Shape of exactly the same size.

   Note that if the path is even slightly not rectangular, it will create a "Polygon Shape", which won't work. If this happens, you will have to go through the points and line them up first.

Now you can select all your Rectangle Shapes and edit their corners in the Transform panel.