# How can i change the radius of the rounded rectangle on AI

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, shapes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to modify the corner radius on rounded rectangle in Illustrator?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5472/how-to-modify-the-corner-radius-on-rounded-rectangle-in-illustrator)

can't seem to manupulate the rounded rectangle on Adobe Illustrator... forgot the shortcut! Any help??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can remember you can't change the radius of the rounded corner if you created your shape by using 'Rounded Rectangle Tool'.

However, you can create a rectangle and apply rounded corners from (CS3) Effect > Convert To Shape > Rounded Rectangle and be able to change the radius later on.

If you ask me its crazy to not to be able to change the radius from the Rectangle Tool!

As for the shortcut, you should just map a key combination for the Rounded Rectangle Effect and use it whenever you need.